# ActionScript 3 Event doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new in AS, and trying to make my first application. I have a class, that showld manage some events, like keyboard key pressing:

```
public class GameObjectController extends Sprite
{
    var textField:TextField;

    public function GameObjectController()
    {
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
    }

    private function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        trace("123");
    }
}
```

but when I'm running it, and pressing any button, nothing happands. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you map the button with your class `GameObjectController`?

Comment: looks like I didn't. What do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `stage.addEventListener()` for `KeyboardEvent`s.

The reason for this is that whatever you add the event to needs focus, and the `stage` always has focus.

If `GameObjectController` isn't the document class, it will need to have `stage` parsed to its constructor for this to work, or it will need to be added to the stage first. The former will be less messy to implement.

```
public function GameObjectController(stage:Stage)
{
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the keyboard event to the stage and import the KeyboardEvent class.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class GameObjectController extends Sprite
    {
        public function GameObjectController()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownEventHandler);
        }

        private function keyDownEventHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            trace(event);
        }
    }
}
```